# Fancybox : Changing dynamically data-fancybox-group

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a huge gallery of images with a filter system that's highlight only images that I choose from the filter. So when a I set a filter on my gallery I change dynamically the data-fancybox-group to make a gallery only between the image that I filter but Fancybox seem to don't like it...

So when i switched the filter when I try to click on a images after a filter change the fancybox dosen't work at all. Anybody have a clue on that?

Thanks!

Here is the code of Fancybox :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 openEffect : 'fade',
 closeEffect : 'fade',
 prevEffect : 'fade',
 nextEffect : 'fade',
 prevSpeed : 'normal',
 nextSpeed : 'normal',
 arrows : true,
 closeBtn : true
});
```

Here my filter code :

```
$(".menu-gallery li a").click(function (){

//My filter menu have a id's
var thisID = this.id;

//Loop in the gallery to show or hide the filter image with the selected filter
$(".list-item li div").each(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass(thisID) ) {
        $(this).removeClass('hide');
        //Change the data group on the fly to make a gallery only with the selected filter image
        $("a", this).attr('data-fancybox-group',thisID);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('hide');        
    }

});

});
```

Comment: so is it an ID or class? does your condition evaluates if the selector has a class with the value of the ID attribute?